# Dynamic Path Import - Angular Component

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any way to import components, or anything for that matter, in a format like this where there is a conditional which decides which one to use?

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

if (environment.envName == 'dev')
    import { ListInventoryComponent, ConfirmDeleteDialog } from 'this_local_path';
else
    import { ListInventoryComponent, ConfirmDeleteDialog } from 'this_npm_package_path';
```

I have local components and modules that I am developing and creating npm packages from, but also would like to be able to test them without changing every reference to it in the code.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot conditionally import components that way. What you should use instead is something called `Dynamic imports`.

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

(Plus there are many other guides on the internet about it).

An example would be:

```js
const getDynamicComponent = async (envName) => {
    let dynamicComponent;

    if (envName === 'dev') {
        dynamicComponent = await import('this_local_path');
    } else {
        dynamicComponent = await import('this_npm_package_path');
    }

    return dynamicComponent;
}
```